# How do I specify file search parameters?

Tags: nautilus, gui, search

How do I specify search parameters other than file name?

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Search]

I want to, for example, retrieve a list of JPEGs on my USB drive that are larger than 1 MB.

I am interested in GUI solutions only — something I would feel comfortable recommending to a novice user who has come to me for help with Ubuntu.

Comment: If you're willing to use the terminal, you can enter all kinds of search parameters and harness some of the true power of linux, by using the "find" command.  `man find` will get you started, and `find --help` will remind you once you get to know it a bit.  Or, search the net for articles on "linux find", or check [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find).  As for the nautilus search, it says "Search for files by Name", so that's all you can really expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Try typing `.` first in the search entry, then you can add options.

OR

You could try gnome-search-tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool
```

You could also launch it with custom otions in the current nautilus path using a nautilus script or nautilus-actions.

Comment: Does adding `.` work because it's a wildcard or because most files have an extension?